# V-deep selector equivalent in TailwindCSS?

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs3, tailwind-css, tiptap

I'm using the `v-deep` selector to style `tiptap`, a rich text editor. For that the `.ProseMirror` class has to be accessed like so (`SCSS`):

```
editor-content {
    // ... styles
    &::v-deep(.ProseMirror) {
      // ... styles
    }
}
```

But how do I style the `.ProseMirror` class with `TailwindCSS`? I can't add classes to it, at least I don't know how. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Tailwind can be used like regular CSS.
Try that one

```css
editor-content {
  &::v-deep(.ProseMirror) {
    @apply bg-red-500;
  }
}
```